# Implementing PicketLink as iDP in Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, saml, picketlink

Excuse my ignorance but can PicketLink be implemented as an IDP within weblogic?

I am looking to create a light weight IDP Proxy to be able to accept SAML requests and issue SAML Assertions based on simple authentication handled elsewhere so not looking for anything that provides too much.

I wondered if picketlink offered a simple API to do this and whether it would work on a welbogic domain.

Comment: Are you looking or something other than https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SAMLEJBIntegrationwithPicketLinkSTSonWeblogic and https://access.redhat.com/solutions/396243 (need login for the second link)

Comment: Hi, I have looked at both of these articles but neither relate to actually deploying picketlink within a Weblogic environment.

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic has its own, built-in SAML implementation that is tightly integrated with the rest of their platform. It is fully configurable from their admin console. Use that instead of PicketLink.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13707/saml.htm#SECMG252